# How to get 3D position using Monocular vision and OpenCV

Tags: opencv, 3d, camera

How is it possible to determine an object's 3D position using one camera and OpenCV when the camera is kept at (say) 45 degrees with respect to the ground ?

Answer (score 1):

Two types of motion can be applied to camera in 3D world: translation and rotation. It's not possible to infer depth from mono camera, if there is no translation. You should check stereo vision for the details.

Simply, you need to recover essential matrix where E = [t_x]R and if t_x = 0, which means you are using monocular vision. There is no way to recover this by classical stereo vision.

However, there are some methods that uses depth of training dataset to infer the depth of test image. Please check [this slide](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse590v/13au/cse590v_au13_wk2_depthtransfer.pdf). They published their code for Matlab; however, you can easily implement it by yourself.

Comment: You can get the depth with monocular vision if the object size, focal length and the distance are fixed.

Comment: Sure, I assume that there is no information about the object.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more accurate result, you can use deep learning models to estimate the depth of the pixels in an input image. There are some open-source models available such as this [one](https://github.com/cogaplex-bts/bts). However, note that `bts` model is trained with `KITTI` dataset from an autonomous vehicle perspective. To have better results, you need to have a dataset that is relevant to your application. Then use frameworks such `bts` to train a model for depth estimation. This model will provide you with point clouds of a single image with `(x,y,z)` coordinates.